# Is it possible to Give IIS Users Permissions Outside of inetpub?

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

I am trying to give IIS full control permissions to a folder located on the `C:` drive of the machine that is hosting the website. It contains database files that are necessary for my application. Is there some way to give explicit permissions for IIS?

Someone posted that I could give NETWORK SERVICE full control over the directory, so I've already granted The NETWORK SERVICE account full permissions and I'm still not able to access the database files. Everything works fine when I store a copy of the database files inside of `\inetpub\wwwroot folder`.

IIS Version 8.5.9600.16384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Application Pool and grant the permissions to the [App Pool identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/ensure-security-isolation-for-web-sites#application-pool-identities), or set the identity to a user who has the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a local database? if it is local, open port 1433. [SQL Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

choose the one that suits you